# Changing GTK label in C using signal_connect

Tags: c, user-interface, gtk, signals

Hello I am making GUI in GTK I have some menu items, and I am trying to change main label after clicking a mouse on specific menu element.

```
widgets[i][0] = gtk_menu_item_new_with_label(arrayOfStrings[i]);
//arrayOfStrings is : char** arrayOfStrings
gtk_menu_shell_append(GTK_MENU_SHELL(indicator_menu), widgets[i][0]);
```

I was trying this:

```
void set_main_label(GtkWidget *widget)
{
    app_indicator_set_label(indicator, arrayOfString[2],arrayOfString[2]);
}
```

and after this I call it like:

```
g_signal_connect(widgets[i][0], "activate",G_CALLBACK(set_main_label), widgets[i][0]);
```

But my problem is that *void set_main_label(void)* must have void argument. And I need to pass there string (char*) which is stored in arrayOfStrings. What do you suggest? Now I can change label only to one specific string set in *set_main_label* function, but I cannot pass it as an argument into function, what do you suggest? .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what the `user_data` parameter is for. `set_main_label()` does not have a `void` argument list - check the [documentation](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkMenuItem.html#GtkMenuItem-activate):

```
void
user_function (GtkMenuItem *widget,
               gpointer     user_data)
```

You can pass any argument you like into the callback via the `user_data` parameter. But it must be known at the time you connect the signal.

So you could do something like this:

```
void
set_main_label(GtkMenuItem *widget, gpointer user_data)
{
    const char *label = (const char *)user_data;
    app_indicator_set_label(indicator, label, label);
}

g_signal_connect(widgets[i][0], "activate",
    G_CALLBACK(set_main_label), arrayOfString[2]);
```

Comment: Also, since you were confused with the `void f(void)` thing: [`g_signal_connect()` only takes a `void (*f)(void)` (`GCallback`) to have a function pointer type to begin with. `g_signal_connect()` doesn't care what the actual signature of the function is, only the signal emitting code does, and the `G_CALLBACK(...)` forces your function to look like a `void (*f)(void)` to the compiler.](https://developer.gnome.org/gobject/stable/gobject-Closures.html#GCallback) (This is one of the only, if not the only, times a function cast is ever permissible anywhere. Do not cast functions anywhere else.)